# I can´t get out my array from a function to the main in c

Tags: c

In `escribirVect(suma[MAX])`, the compiler tells me that `suma` is undeclared but I declared it in my function `sumarV`, how can I use my variable 'suma' in `main`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

void leerVect(int vect[MAX]);
void escribirVect (int v[MAX]);
void sumarV (int vector1[MAX], int vector2[MAX]);

int main ()
{
    int vector1[MAX], vector2[MAX];
    printf("Introduzca los valores del primer vector: \n");
    leerVect(vector1);
    printf("Introduzca los valores del segundo vector: \n");
    leerVect(vector2);
    sumarV(vector1, vector2);
    escribirVect(suma[MAX]);  // here is the problem

    return 0;
}

void leerVect(int v[MAX])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("Introduzca el valor de v[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
}

void escribirVect (int v[MAX])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("El valor de la suma de el elemento v[%d] es: %d \n", i, v[i]);
    }
}

void sumarV (int vector1[MAX], int vector2[MAX])
{
    int suma[MAX], i;   //here is the problem
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        suma[i]=vector1[i]+vector2[i];  //here is the problem
    }
}
```

The problem disappears when I comment 'here is the problem' inside the code.

Comment: And the compiler is correct. Where do you declare `suma`? Not in the `main` function where you use it. Perhaps you should re-read your books or tutorials about *scoping*?

Comment: `suma[MAX]` is not defined in the `main()`, it is defined inside `sumarV()`

Comment: Furthermore, `suma[MAX]` is not the array, it's a *single element* of the array. And considering your definition in the `sumarV` function, it would also be *out of bounds*

Comment: Take a look at [scopes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Declare `suma` in `main` and pass it to `sumaV()`

```
int main ()
{
    int vector1[MAX], vector2[MAX], suma[MAX];

    ...
    sumarV(vector1, vector2, suma);
```

Then, in the function

```
void sumarV (int vector1[MAX], int vector2[MAX], int suma[MAX])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        suma[i]=vector1[i]+vector2[i];
    }
}
```

Finally, don't pass the number of elements

```
escribirVect(suma[MAX]);  // here is the problem
```

just pass the array, which decays into a pointer to the first element:

```
escribirVect(suma);
```

Comment: For consistency with the other parameters of `sumarV`, I'd replace `int *suma` with `int suma[MAX]`. Also, OP's original code has a problem in the call `escribirVect(suma[MAX]);`, which should be `escribirVect(suma);`.